# Can spring request reply can be implemented with client side using spring kafka API's and server side using apache kafka API?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Can spring request reply can be implemented with client side using spring kafka API's and server side using apache kafka API ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring for Apache Kafka provides request/reply using the `ReplyingKafkaTemplate` and `@KafkaListener` with a `@SendTo`.

[Documentation here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.6.0/reference/html/#replying-template).

**EDIT**

When using multiple client instances...

> f you have multiple client instances and you do not configure them as discussed in the preceding paragraph, each instance needs a dedicated reply topic. An alternative is to set the KafkaHeaders.REPLY_PARTITION and use a dedicated partition for each instance. The Header contains a four-byte int (big-endian). The server must use this header to route the reply to the correct partition (@KafkaListener does this). In this case, though, the reply container must not use Kafka’s group management feature and must be configured to listen on a fixed partition (by using a TopicPartitionOffset in its ContainerProperties constructor).

> When configuring with a single reply topic, each instance must use a different group.id. In this case, all instances receive each reply, but only the instance that sent the request finds the correlation ID. This may be useful for auto-scaling, but with the overhead of additional network traffic and the small cost of discarding each unwanted reply. When you use this setting, we recommend that you set the template’s sharedReplyTopic to true, which reduces the logging level of unexpected replies to DEBUG instead of the default ERROR.

Comment: Multiple instances of client causing reply timeout exception.

org.springframework.kafka.requestreply.KafkaReplyTimeoutException: Reply timed out
        at org.springframework.kafka.requestreply.ReplyingKafkaTemplate.lambda$scheduleTimeout$3(ReplyingKafkaTemplate.java:342) [spring-kafka-2.5.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.5.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)

Comment: when I run single instance of client not getting any reply timeout exceptions.

Comment: Don't put logs in comments; unreadable - edit the question instead. If you are not using Spring on the server side, the server side needs to return the reply to the right reply topic and include the correlation id header; you need to show your code and configuration (both sides).

Comment: When using multiple client instances, if you are using the same reply topic for each, you need to use a different group id, so both instances get the reply; you can set `sharedReplyTopic` to `true` to suppress the log message on the other instance, or you should use a different reply topic/partition for each instance - see [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.6.0/reference/html/#replying-template).

Comment: Tons of thanks for your help, I've tried with different groupId and which works as expected. But unfortunately we are gonna use load balancer in PROD and K8S.
In that case how we can manage this groupId ?

Is there any other way that we can solve this issue(request and reply)?

Comment: You can simply use a `UUID.randomUUID().toString()` for the `group.id` to get a unique `group.id` for each instance. It's not clear what problem you expect with a load balancer. As I said, the other solution is to use a unique reply topic for each instance.